# Scrapy python following pagination

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

I'm having problem following pagination of this website: http://gamesurf.tiscali.it/ps4/recensioni.html

My spider part of code :

```
for pag in response.css('li.square-nav'):
    next = pag.css('li.square-nav > a > span::text').extract_first()
    if next=='»':
        next_page_url = pag.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

If i run my spider on windows terminal it works on all pages of the website, but when i deploy to scrapinghub and run from the button in the dashboard, spider scrape only the first page of the website.
Between log messages there is a warning:

```
[py.warnings] /app/__main__.egg/reccy/spiders/reccygsall.py:21: 
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to 
Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal.
```

Line 21 is this:

```
if next=='»':
```

I have checked problem is not caused by robot.txt.
How can i fix this?
Thanks

Here the entire spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reccygsall'
    allowed_domains = ['gamesurf.tiscali.it']
    start_urls = ['http://gamesurf.tiscali.it/ps4/recensioni.html']

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css("div.boxn1"):
        item = {
            'title':  quote.css('div.content.fulllayer > h3 > a::text').extract_first(),
            'text':  quote.css('div.content.fulllayer > h3 > a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
        }
        yield item


    for pag in response.css('li.square-nav'):
        next = pag.css('li.square-nav > a > span::text').extract_first()
        if next=='»':
            next_page_url = pag.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if next_page_url:
                next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: You can try to locate an element with a xpath: `//li[@class="square-nav"]/a[span]/@href`

Comment: Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the very beginning of your spider module source file, and use `if next==u'»':`

Comment: next==u'»':
               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I Have edited my question inserting the entire code. Can you write the exactly code i should write to obtain what i want? I don't know xpath

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reccygsall'
    allowed_domains = ['gamesurf.tiscali.it']
    start_urls = ['http://gamesurf.tiscali.it/ps4/recensioni.html']

    contatore = 0

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css("div.boxn1"):
            item = {
                'title':  quote.css('div.content.fulllayer > h3 > a::text').extract_first(),
                'text':  quote.css('div.content.fulllayer > h3 > a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
            }
            yield item


            self.contatore = self.contatore + 1
            a = 0
            for pag in response.css('li.square-nav'):
                next = pag.css('a::text').extract_first()
                if next is None:
                    a = a+1;
                        if (self.contatore < 2) or (a > 1):
                            next_page_url = pag.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()

                            if next_page_url:
                                next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
                                yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```